# Получение информации о пользователе, имея только его id, с помощью vk_api

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, api, вконтакте

Я использую `python3` и `vk_api` как я могу получить имя пользователя и фамилию, если у меня есть только его vk **id**?

Этот метод не работает: я хочу получить аналогичную информацию о другом пользователе, этот метод возвращает информацию о текущем пользователе (user).

```
info = user.account.getInfo()
```

Есть ли функция в `vk_api`, которая получает идентификатор пользователя и возвращает информацию о нем? Как я могу получить имя пользователя и фамилию, имея только его идентификатор(id), из скрипта `python`? Спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: Метод `users.get` с параметром `user_ids`, [документация](https://vk.com/dev/users.get).

Comment: Спасибо! Я уж как раз нашел

Answer (score 0):

***Код:***

```py
info = user.users.get(user_ids = id)
```

[*Документация*](https://vk.com/dev/users.get)